# What is the easiest way to query for a date in a range using Rails 4 and postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to select all records with a created_by attribute in a date range:

```
@start = params[:start].to_datetime
@end = params[:end].to_datetime
@registrations = Registration.where("created_at >= #{ @start } and created_at <= #{ @end }")
```

But I get an error from postgres that says:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "T00"
LINE 1: ...M "registrations"  WHERE (created_at >= 2013-06-01T00:00:00+...
```

I've been searching on this one, but Google isn't coming through this time...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way, in my opinion will be to use range in `where` clause as:

```
Registration.where(created_at: @start..@end)
```

This query will not be prone to SQL injections either, since `@start` and `@end` are already typecasted in `DateTime` in your query.

Answer (score 2):

Try binding the query parameters like this:

```
@registrations = Registration.where "created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?",
                                    params[:start].to_datetime,
                                    params[:end].to_datetime
```

This allows you to bind the parameters in a way that helps prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@start = params[:start].to_datetime
@end = params[:end].to_datetime
@registrations = Registration.where(created_at: @start..@end)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@start = params[:start].to_datetime
@end = params[:end].to_datetime
@registrations = Registration.where("created_at >= '#{@start}' and created_at <= '#{@end}'")
```